# JavaFX Application Thread to Task Communication

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, concurrency

I've been learning about JavaFX's Tasks and using these to communicate with the Application thread using `Platform.runLater` or the task's `updateValue` method etc. However, my `Task` needs to know when a user presses a button on the GUI as this could change the value needed to be returned by the Task's `updateValue` method. How do I go about doing this? I know how to respond to button press events on single threaded applications but am not sure how do deal with it in a thread-safe manner.

## Update:

This is what I have so far, is this a sensible way of implementing the button event?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.nio.IntBuffer;

public class TaskExample extends Application {
    
    private Canvas canvas;
    private PixelWriter pixel_writer;   

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        canvas = new Canvas(256, 256);
        pixel_writer = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter();
   
        MyTask task = new MyTask();

        task.valueProperty().addListener((c) -> {
            if(task.getValue() != null) {
                update(task.getValue());
            }
        });     
        
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);     
        thread.start();
        
        Button button = new Button("Button 1");
        
        // On the button click event it calls the eventFired() method
        button.setOnAction((event) -> {
            task.eventFired();
        });  
        
        Pane pane = new VBox();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(canvas, button);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();    
        
    }

    
    public void update(IntBuffer data) {
        pixel_writer.setPixels(
            0,
            0,
            256,
            256,
            PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(),
            data,
            256
        );  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class MyTask extends Task<IntBuffer> {

        public void eventFired() {
            System.out.println("Event fired");
        }
    
        public void update(IntBuffer data) {
            updateValue(data);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected IntBuffer call() throws InterruptedException {

            while(true) {
                for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    IntBuffer data = IntBuffer.allocate(256*256);                   
                    for(int j=0; j<256*256; j++) {
                        switch(i) {
                            case 0: data.put(0xFF0000FF); break;
                            case 1: data.put(0xFF00FF00); break;
                            case 2: data.put(0xFFFF0000); break;
                        }
                        
                    }
                    data.rewind();                      
                    update(data);
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, but it doesn't actually do what you describe: i.e. the two threads don't interact. When you press the button, the task will display a message to the console on the FX Application Thread. But nothing changes that affects what happens on the background thread. So if you want to ask "will this work", you need to actually show some code that does what you describe.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that they didn't interact. How do I go about running the `eventFired` method on the background thread?

Comment: You can't run that on the background thread. But presumably just sending a message to the console is not what you actually want to do. You want to do something (no one except you knows what at this stage) that changes what is happening in the `call` method, no?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is letting the `call` method know that the button was pressed. So based on your comment to @Eudy Contreras' answer, would you suggest atomic variables and listeners are the way to go?

Comment: Changing the state of a variable in a way that is thread-safe is, I think, what you are wanting to do. Atomic references are an easy way to make this thread safe (but may be overkill, depending on the details). JavaFX properties are single-threaded, so using those and listeners here would be quite difficult (at best).

Comment: I guess: "You can't run that on the background thread" is not completely true, there would be ways to do it. But I don't think that's what you're looking for. You probably need to clarify what you want to happen here. And if you're really looking to run tasks at a specified interval, there may be better solutions entirely.

Comment: I'm writing a Gameboy emulator. I've got the emulator running in a `Task` and am using a `Canvas` as the display. The emulator supplies the canvas with pixel data using the Task's `updateValue` method. However the emulator needs to know when buttons are pressed so that it can pause what ever it is doing and trigger an interrupt.

Comment: Hmm. It's not really clear that a background thread and task are the correct approach at all here. I can't really see what the background thread would provide other than a game loop, which is effectively already present in the way JavaFX is structured. (In fact, in your example (and my answer below), you share mutable data in the form of the `IntBuffer` between two threads, and it's not at all clear this is properly synchronized.) I recommend reading [this](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html), which relies on [this](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html).

Answer (score 2):

What I would do here is to think about ways to refactor what you are doing to avoid communication between two different threads. For example, instead of thinking of what you are doing as one long-running task that updates the UI as it progresses, think of it as a series of individual tasks that each update the UI when they complete. The [`ScheduledService` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) provides the machinery to manage these tasks and communicate between them and the FX Application Thread in a clean and safe way:

```
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TaskExample extends Application {

    private Canvas canvas;
    private PixelWriter pixel_writer;   

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        canvas = new Canvas(256, 256);
        pixel_writer = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter();


        MyService service = new MyService();
        service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(1));

        service.valueProperty().addListener((ols, oldData, newData) -> {
            if(newData != null) {
                update(newData);
            }
        });     
        service.start();

        Button button = new Button("Button 1");


        Pane pane = new VBox();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(canvas, button);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();    

    }


    public void update(IntBuffer data) {
        pixel_writer.setPixels(
            0,
            0,
            256,
            256,
            PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(),
            data,
            256
        );  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class MyService extends ScheduledService<IntBuffer> {

        // both instance variables accessed only on FX Application Thread:

        private final int[] colors = {0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFF0000} ;

        private int count = -1 ;

        @Override
        protected Task<IntBuffer> createTask() {
            // invoked on FX Application Thread
            count = (count + 1) % colors.length ;
            return new MyTask(colors[count]);
        }
    }

    class MyTask extends Task<IntBuffer> {

        private final int color ;

        MyTask(int color) {
            // invoked on FX Application Thread:
            this.color = color ;
        }

        @Override
        protected IntBuffer call() {
            // invoked on background thread:
            IntBuffer data = IntBuffer.allocate(256*256);   
            int[] a = new int[256*256];
            Arrays.fill(a, color);
            data.put(a, 0, a.length);
            data.rewind();
            return data ;
        }

    }
}
```

You haven't been very specific about how the UI is supposed to interact with the background thread, but if you wanted to change the behavior of the service when the button is pressed, you would now be changing the behavior of the `createTask` method, which is invoked on the FX Application Thread, instead of changing the behavior of a method already running on a different thread. This avoids any "low-level" concerns about synchronization.

For example:

```
class MyService extends ScheduledService<IntBuffer> {

    // all instance variables accessed only on FX Application Thread:

    private final int[][] colors = {
            {0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFF0000},
            {0xFF00FFFF, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFFFFFF00}
    };

    private int count = -1 ;
    private int scheme = 0 ;

    @Override
    protected Task<IntBuffer> createTask() {
        // invoked on FX Application Thread
        count = (count + 1) % colors[scheme].length ;
        return new MyTask(colors[scheme][count]);
    }

    public void changeScheme() {
        // invoked on FX Application Thread
        scheme = (scheme + 1) % colors.length ;
    }
}
```

and then just

```
button.setOnAction(e -> service.changeScheme());
```

Adding a call to `service.restart();` here will force the change to happen as soon as possible:

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    service.changeScheme();
    service.restart();
});
```

There is pretty much always a way to refactor your code to take advantage of the library classes like this to avoid low-level communication between threads.